# How to rotate an arc in canvas using context?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Question: How can I rotate my arc 45degrees using the canvas context?

https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/bGbmOZp

```js
const c = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");


const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight} = c;
const x = offsetWidth/2;
const y = offsetHeight/2;
const radius = 50;
const halfRadius = radius/2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x - halfRadius, y - halfRadius, radius, 0, 1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
```

Comment: Do you really want to rotate it or just to make it go from 4PM to 2PM? https://jsfiddle.net/ajefuw5p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **ctx.save()** and **ctx.translate(x, y)** to make proper rotation and don't forget to restore the contexte with **ctx.restore()**

```
const c = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");


const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight} = c;
const x = offsetWidth/2;
const y = offsetHeight/2;
const radius = 50;
const halfRadius = radius/2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.save()
ctx.translate(x-halfRadius, y - halfRadius);
ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180 );
ctx.arc(0 , 0, radius, 0, 1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to rotate the context before drawing the arc.

```js
const c = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");


const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight} = c;
const x = offsetWidth/2;
const y = offsetHeight/2;
const radius = 50;
const halfRadius = radius/2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rotate((Math.PI / 180) * 45);
ctx.arc(x - halfRadius, y - halfRadius, radius, 0, 1.5*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300">
```